# What is the reason of this two Shivas under Kali?

Tags: shiva, kali

[image]

In some images we see **two** Shivas under Goddess Kali and in some images She stand  on a single Shiva.

What is the scriptural reference of the two Shivas ?

[image]

Comment: Is it related to a story where Shiva was born as Mahishasura ?

Comment: One is showing the Viparit-Rati posture but which Goddess is it? Which Dhyana Sloka used?